# Handling IIS Requests Current in a SignaR application?

Tags: iis-7, configuration, signalr

I have a SignalR application running in production, where the enter code here `Requests Current` value exceeded 5000, rendering a `503 Service Unavailable` error.  So I updated the Aspnet.config with the following to increase the `Requests Current` value

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <applicationPool 
            maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="20000" 
            maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="20000" 
            requestQueueLimit="20000" />
    </system.web>
    <runtime>
        <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="false" />
        <legacyImpersonationPolicy enabled="true"/>
        <alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy enabled="false"/>
        <SymbolReadingPolicy enabled="1" />
        <shadowCopyVerifyByTimestamp enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" />
</configuration>
```

However, now the Requests Current value is able to increase past 5000, and at just above 10,000, the service is unavailable.    I am only seeing a small number of Requests Queued ( less than 100) at times.

[image]

What else needs to be configured to allow this to operate properly?

**-- Update --**

After using 0.5.2, the Requests Current seems to stabilize, which is a significant improvement.  This test has run for a little over two hours, whereas within less than 30 minutes the req's current would just continue to build.

Still some increase in memory consumption, but possibly not due to the Req's Current:

[image: Requests Current - improved]

Comment: First thing you should do is update to SignalR 0.5.2. There's bugs in a previous version of SignalR that can cause multiple connections per clients etc. There was also another bug that left zombie connections hanging aroud forever. 

About performance, did you read this? https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Performance

Comment: Alright.  I'm sure that I don't have any memory leaks in my code, but I'd like to know if those zombie connections account for the gradual increase of unreleased memory consumption?

Comment: I can't tell you anything for sure, it's best you profile your application instead of me making assumptions.